# how to find if an arraylist is single dimensional or multi dimensional in C#.?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays

In C#, i have created ArrayList using structures. so it creates multi dimensional array list.

```
public struct ParameterValues
{
    public ArrayList al;
};

ArrayList alCombined = new ArrayList();

for(int i=0; i < CONDITION , i++)
    alCombined.Add(obj.pValue.al);
```

The dimension of `ArrayList alCombined` depends on the CONDITION. if its 1, then 1-D arraylist is created. Else multidimensional Arraylist is getting created.

Now in order to access the elements of alCombined, i'm typecasting it and accessing, like

```
(((ArrayList)al[i])[j])
```

But if its a 1-D arraylist then error occurs as type casting to Arraylist is not possible.

So I need a solution for this, or how to find if its a single/ multi dimensional arraylist.
FYI: it should not depend on CONDITION variable. like if d condition is more than one, then it will be multi dimensional for sure.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's really no such thing as a "multi-dimensional ArrayList". `ArrayLists` don't have a particular element type. You might have one element which is an integer, another which is a string, another which is an `int[]` and another which is an `ArrayList` itself.

A few suggestions on your code:

- Mutable structs are a bad idea. Avoid them. Chances are you don't really want a struct in the first place, and mutable structs can cause all kinds of unexpected behaviour.
- Public fields are a bad idea. Avoid them. Fields are an implementation detail, and shouldn't be part of the API.
- `ArrayList` is effectively deprecated - use generic collections instead. That will make the type information much more clearer.
- You should design your data structure so that you don't get into this sort of situation. Ideally, there should be very few execution-time type checks going on in your code. Perhaps if you could give us more information on what you're trying to achieve, we could help you redesign it.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
if(al[i] is ArrayList)
{
   ...
}
```